# Why doesn't Visual Studio publish all of the required files?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using VS2022 Community, and have a solution that has a Blazor app, and a few minimal API projects (amongst others).

When I want to publish one of these, I right-click the project in Solution Explorer, choose Publish and click the Publish button. I have set up a publish profile that publishes to a folder, from which I manually FTP the files to the server.(*)

At some point in the past, I guess this must have worked correctly, as I have been working on this solution for over a year, and never had any problems.

However, I now need to move the Blazor site to a new server. I published, and used FTP to copy the files to the new server, but found the site wasn't working. It turns out that VS had not copied all the required files to the Publish folder, and so critical DLLs were missing when I copied the files to the server. These seem to be a random collection, including most EF Core, some ASP.NET and a few third-party DLLs. Can't see any pattern as to which are not copied, but it's consistent each time I publish.

I presume that whatever stage VS decided to stop including these files was when they were already on the server (from a previous publish), so being missing from the Publish folder wasn't an issue, as they were already on the server.

I tried cloning a new copy of the solution from source control, but had exactly the same issue.

So now I'm stuck, as I don't have the critical files in the Publish folder. Another dev working on the same solution can publish and get all the required files.

Anyone able to explain why I don't get the files, and (more to the point) how I fix this?

Thanks

(*) I don't use VS's built-in FTP as our firewall seems to block it. However, as the issue is with the publish itself, I don't think this is relevant.

Comment: The required files which have not been copied what their types are and the location? In addition, could you please include your project structure along with those file location? On top of this, while attempting publish what were their content type?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Not sure what you mean. I already said that the missing files were DLLs, including most EF Core ones, some ASP.NET ones and a few 3rd-party DLLs. Their location is my `.nuget` folder. No idea about content type, as the DLLs are pulled in by VS from Nuget package references, not direct references to the DLLs. What project structure would you like to see? Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Also, another dev can publish fine, so I don't see how it can be connected to the project structure, etc, as he will have the same code as me.

Comment: I understand, however, its hard to investigate your issue with this description as nothing can be troubleshoot as no scenario I can reproduce at my end. What happens if you create a new demo project and published it? Still files missing there? So that it can be narrowed down whether the problem in project or machine.